# Почему функция не выполняется?

Tags: java, android

```
if (isCancelled())//Выполняется 
    return false; //Не выполняется. Вверху false
publishProgress(values); //Не выполняется (почему?)
return true; //Выполняется
```

Просто перепрыгивает будто через функцию. В ней тоже брейпоинты ставил, тишина

---

```
 boolean b = isCancelled();
 if (b)
     return false;
 publishProgress(values);
 return true;
```

Переделал так, тут вообще интересно. `b` инициализируется как `true` а условие перепрыгивает на `return true`

---

Удалил послностью приложение с телефона. В студии сделал `build clean` build rebuild`. То же самое

Comment: Что-то тут не так. `b инициализируется как true` это вы в отладчике увидели?

Comment: @iksuy да, условие должно быть `true` и должно выполниться `return false`

Comment: `isCancelled()`, `values` что там? Что в `onProgressUpdate`?

Comment: "должно быть" или вы это явно видели? Программа выполняет ровно то, что вы ей говорите, ничего сверхестесственного не будет. у вас не написано `if(true)` у вас там переменная, которая получает значение из `isCancelled`. Там явно что-то не так.

Comment: `values` - там лежит сборщик `View` для андроида и его `id`. `isCancelled()` - `true`. в `onProgressUpdate()` `super.onProgressUpdate(values);` и инфлатинг `View` и установка его в `Activity`

Comment: Что значит `isCancelled` - `true`? Это метод такой, `boolean isCancelled(){ return true; }` или как?

Comment: @iksuy `boolean b = isCancelled();` отладчик показывает что `b == true`, по логике `if (true) тело....` должно выполнить тело, в данном случае одну строку

Comment: @iksuy `isCancelled()` - это функция маячок в `Android`. Просто геттер

Comment: Может быть вы изменили код, но не скомпилировали (или не перезапустили приложение), у вас старая версия .class файлов, соответственно в отладчике каша получается. Попробуйте закрыть эмулятор, пересобрать проект с очисткой старой версии и посмотреть, что будет.

Comment: Добавлю к посту iksuy, что имеет смысл в эмуляторе(или на девайсе) удалить приложение. Это извесная бага(а кому то и фича) последних студий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку короче. Очень странно как-то. Дело в том, что я инициализировал объект `Asynctask`а в методе `onCreate` activity.
В методе `onStart` - делал `myAsyncTask.cancel(false);` (Именно это делает `isCancelled()` равным `true`),
А в методе `onStop()` `myAsyncTask.cancel(true)`.
Просто убрал полностью метод `onStart` с `myAsyncTask.cancel(false);` и все стало нормально, но метод `onCancelled()` вызывается все равно, судя по логам. Что-то я намудрил, да еще и `java` тупит, вот и наложилось это все друг на друга. Спасибо всем, кто помогал

---

Плюс мне пришлось схитрить и проверку `isCancelled()` организовать следующим способом:

```
boolean ret;

    int choice = (isCancelled()) ? 1 : 0;

    if (choice == 0) {
        publishProgress(values);
        ret = true;
    }
    else
        ret = false;

    return ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это глюк отладчика/компилятора/оптимизатора, бряки на строках с `return` глючат и часто прыгают к последнему `return`. К сожалению с этим ничего не сделать.

Comment: Ого... У джавы ещё и с отладкой проблемы?

Comment: Ну эту проблему я бы не назвал сильно неприятной, а других проблем с отладкой я не встречал.